# Does the uncertainty principle say that conservation of momentum is violated in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The uncertainty principle of Heisenberg says that the uncertainty in the position of a particle multiplied by the uncertainty of the momentum of a particle is always more than or equal to $\frac{\hbar}{2}$:

$$\Delta x \Delta p \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

Rearranging, you get this:

$$\Delta p \ge \frac{\hbar}{2\Delta x},$$

which means that the uncertainty in momentum will never be $0$ unless the uncertainty in position is $\infty$.
But that can never happen... I mean at maximum the uncertainty in position can't be more than a certain value because the universe doesn't have infinite space, right? Besides, if you think about electrons around an atom, that’s finite space.

That would mean that there will always be an uncertainty in momentum... Meaning that momentum is not conserved...

This question has been bothering me lately. It would be great if someone could give me an explanation.

Comment: "there will always be an uncertainty in momentum...Meaning that momentum is not conserved..." I don't see how this follows.

Comment: "*That would mean that there will always be an uncertainty in momentum...Meaning that momentum is not conserved...*" What interaction are you considering that you want momentum to be conserved during?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I mean momentum in collisions...And the other question didn't answer my question...The answers in that were awfully complicated....It would be great if you could explain it to me using simple math...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uncertainty principle says that you cannot know position and momentum *simultaneously*. The momentum of a particle on its own can be known to arbitrary precision. The momentum of any object/interaction is always conserved.

Comment: + momentu is conserved in all interactions .  This has been validated in innumerous particle physics experiments.

Comment: Yes, this is implied. But I added interaction. Thanks Anna.

Comment: Does that mean that a well-defined momentum exists for all particles and it's just hidden from us?

Comment: @RyderRude  "hidden" is anthropomorphic. One measures the momentum with the current experimental errors through interactions, at the level of particles  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html      http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html